# How to differentiate this function?

Tags: calculus

Hey I need help differentiating this specific function. I've attempted for quite some time now and my answer seems off. Can someone please differentiate this so I can compare my answer to yours? Thanks in advance

$${y}=\frac{870}{q}+3500 \cdot \frac{e^{(3 q+4 )/820}}{q}.$$

Comment: Can you show us your attempted answer? And I'm guessing you're asking for the derivative with respect to $q$?

Comment: By "derive" do you mean "differentiate"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first term is rather easy, but you'll need to use the quotient rule for the second term.  With that said, you should find that

$$y^{\prime} = -\frac{870}{q^2} + 3500 \frac{q\left(e^{(3q+4)/820}\cdot 3/820\right) - e^{(3q+4)/820}\cdot 1}{q^2}$$

I'll leave the simplification of that to you.